# is there any code which point to my domain in google cloud function?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js

i used cloudflare worker and this code below was ok in there
`addEventListener('fetch', event => {
event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
let url = new URL(request.url);
url.hostname = 'host'; // doesn't accept ip. you can use https://www.noip.com and bypass this restriction
let upstream = new Request(url, request);
return fetch(upstream`

in host, i can replace my domain
in google cloud function i got error
is there any code which trigger domain point to my domain?

i got error
i used too many code for everything

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.